# Can't increase mouse sensitivity

Tags: mouse

I've got a problem increasing my mouse sensitivty and the cursor moves pretty slow at the moment. I've tried using that sensitivity slider in the system settings but it does nothing. I found some articles here and found that I might need to lower the value of 'Device Accel Constant Deceleration', but that's already at its lowest (1.000000). I've also tried changing the polling rate described here:
http://www.urbanterror.info/forums/topic/21844-howto-changing-mouse-polling-rate-on-ubuntu/
but no difference between 100Hz and 500Hz. What else can I do?

Ubuntu 12.04, MS Intellimouse Explorer 3.0

PS: `xinput --list-props 8 | grep Accel` shows this:

```
Device Accel Profile (268): 0  
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (269):   1.000000  
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (270):   1.000000  
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (271):    10.000000
```

Comment: I was able to set `Device Accel Constant Deceleration` below `1` on my system. Do you get an error when you attempt this? For example, setting it to `0.5`.

Comment: Yes:
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  147 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Value in failed request:  0x10d
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  20

Comment: What command are you using to set the property?

Comment: xinput --set-prop 8 269 0.5

Comment: Hmmm...okay, can you post the output of `xinput --list-props 8 | grep Accel` in your question.

Comment: edited the first post

Comment: Okay, those are the same values I have on my system. My last suggestion would be to install `dconf-editor` and use it to edit the `motion-acceleration` and `motion-threshold` keys in `org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse`. Those are the numbers the slider in the settings dialog is supposed to change. if that doesn't work, you'll have to wait for someone else to answer as I have no other suggestions.

Comment: Don't know if it will work, but you can try the "xset" command. Try a high value, like: "xset m 10 20" and see if it helps. (Note the space between the 10 and 20)

Comment: Alright, it looks like we have a success. I reseted 'motion-acceleration' and 'motion-threshold' to -1 in dconf-editor and my mouse sensitivity is way better now. Thank you for the help guys!

Comment: Since `dconf-editor` worked, I posted it as an answer. When you get a chance please accept it so other users can see what worked for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing `dconf-editor` and use it to edit the `motion-acceleration` and `motion-threshold` keys in `org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse`. Those are the numbers the slider in the settings dialog is supposed to change.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177640

Basically:

- Use `xinput list` to find the name of your mouse device
- Run `xinput set-prop 'Name Of Your Mouse' 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 3 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 1`

You can change the `3`s to whatever value you want (larger = increased speed). Leave all the other numbers the same. You'll need to [make the command run on startup](https://askubuntu.com/a/910/986830), since it only lasts for your current session.

Comment: The first answer didn't help but this one did thanks :)