# Ubuntu 14.10 is ignoring touchpad settings

Tags: touchpad, 14.10, chromebook, trackpad

I have opened the mouse & touchpad control panel and moved the touchpad speed to "fast" but it's still very slow. Moving that back and forth makes no difference in speed, it's still ignored. How do I set the cursor speed to be faster? Is there a configuration file I can update?

Ubuntu 14.10
Linux 3.17
Acer C720 Chromebook

Running in chroot (Chrubuntu, booted into via ctrl+L)

Comment: Does [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/511110/205638) help?

Comment: @TheSchwa Unfortunately, no. I changed the `motion-acceleration` and `motion-threshold` to both be 10 but it's still a slow mouse that doesn't accelerate at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was only able to fix this by changing to using the ChromeOS touchpad driver instead of synaptic:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hugegreenbug/cmt
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y libevdevc libgestures  xf86-input-cmt
$ sudo mv /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf.old
$ sudo cp /usr/share/xf86-input-cmt/50-touchpad-cmt-peppy.conf /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
$ sudo reboot
```