# Acer C720 trackpad not working Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: touchpad, 14.10, chromebook

Just installed Ubuntu 14.10 on my acer c720 chromebook. The touchpad is unresponsive.

Comment: Maybe this is related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/551534/ubuntu-14-10-is-ignoring-touchpad-settings

Answer (score 0):

Determine whether a touchpad has been detected
To check if a touchpad has been detected open a terminal and check the input device list given by this command:

```
xinput list
```

If one of the lines mentions a touchpad or glidepoint (perhaps also "Synaptics" or "ALPS"), your touchpad has been detected.

If one of the lines mentions an "ADB mouse", then your touchpad is old. Use the trackpad command line tool to configure it. Here's an example to switch on tapping and dragging:

```
sudo trackpad show
sudo trackpad tap
sudo trackpad drag
```

Follow[this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad#Troubleshooting) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Trackpad works with Linux ver 3.18 and later. I suggest to upgrade to 15.04 which comes with 3.19.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)